# How can I solve this "Function does not return a value on all code paths"

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to do a simple ID generator for my college assignment. But right now I face this problem that it shows "function does not return a value on all paths". The results I get is always the "F" path. What should I do?

```
Private Function GenerateID(ByVal gender As String) As String

    Dim yearJoin As Int32 = Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2)

    If String.Compare(gender, "Male") Then
        Return (yearJoin & "M" & (maxRows + 1).ToString("D3"))
    ElseIf String.Compare(gender, "Female") Then
        Return (yearJoin & "F" & (maxRows + 1).ToString("D3"))
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: you are missing else case at the end. Or just return some value before end of the function

Comment: Do you have genders other than male and female? If not, don't do an ElseIf, but only an Else. But if there is another gender, you'll need to think about what to do in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just return some default value like null in case that any condition is matched:

```
Private Function GenerateID(ByVal gender As String) As String

    Dim yearJoin As Int32 = Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2)

    If String.Compare(gender, "Male") Then
        Return (yearJoin & "M" & (maxRows + 1).ToString("D3"))
    ElseIf String.Compare(gender, "Female") Then
        Return (yearJoin & "F" & (maxRows + 1).ToString("D3"))
    End If
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A method must return a value in any case. So either add an `... Else` to your `If..ElseIf...`, add a final `Return something`(as fallback value) or throw an exception in the case that the provided `gender` is neither `Male` nor `Female`.

I prefer the latter (because what else can it be?):

```
Private Function GenerateID(ByVal gender As String) As String
    Dim yearJoin As String = Date.Today.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2)
    Dim isMale As Boolean = String.Equals(gender, "Male", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    Dim isFemale As Boolean = String.Equals(gender, "Female", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

    If Not isMale AndAlso Not isFemale Then
        Throw New ArgumentException($"{NameOf(gender)} must either be Male or Female", NameOf(gender))
    End If

    Dim maleFemaleLetter = If(isMale, "M", "F")
    maxRows += 1
    Dim id As String = $"{yearJoin}{maleFemaleLetter}{(maxRows).ToString("D3")}"
    Return id
End Function
```

You should also use `Option Strict On`. `String.Compare` return an integer. `Option Strict Off` converts this silently to a `Boolean`. Use `String.Equals` instead. The same with  `String.Substring` which returns a `String` not an `Integer`. Write type-safe code to prevent nasty bugs.